# Ideas on rephrasing the sentence below, please

Tags: writing-advice

"The privilege of serving people and improving their quality of life motivates me to pursue lifelong education and contribution to the dental knowledge and community."

I feel that the last part "dental knowledge and community" is kind of odd parallelism. Any suggestions for rephrasing the sentence above even if it involves using other synonyms?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: '... lifelong education so that I will be better qualified to make a real contribution to dental knowledge, and thus better serve the community.'

Answer (score 1):

I think that 'the privilege of serving people and improving their quality of life' could be condensed to 'Improving people's quality of life...' Or even 'Helping people and improving their quality of life'. It doesn't need the bit about privilege - it sounds a bit simpering or over the top.

I also think that 'motivates me to' could sound more powerful as 'is my motivation'.

I agree with bogle on using 'dentistry' rather than the dental knowledge and community'.

So, in full, this is my take on the sentence:

'Helping people and improving their quality of life is my motivation for pursuing lifelong education to further my contribution to dentistry.'

Answer (score 0):

You can try replacing "the dental knowledge and community" with *dentistry*: "The privilege to serve others and improve their quality of life motivates me to pursue lifelong education, and to make lasting contributions to dentistry."